# SQL Split Multiple Multivalue Columns into Rows

Tags: sql, parsing, split, multivalue

I have data that was sent to me, and I need to normalize it.  The data is in a sql table, but each row has multiple multi value columns.  An example is the following:

```
ID  fname   lname       projects           projdates
1   John    Doe         projA;projB;projC  20150701;20150801;20150901
2   Jane    Smith       projD;;projC       20150701;;20150902
3   Lisa    Anderson    projB;projC        20150801;20150903
4   Nancy   Johnson     projB;projC;projE  20150601;20150822;20150904
5   Chris   Edwards     projA              20150905
```

Needs too look like this:

```
ID  fname   lname      projects projdates
1   John    Doe          projA  20150701
1   John    Doe          projB  20150801
1   John    Doe          projC  20150901
2   Jane    Smith        projD  20150701
2   Jane    Smith        projC  20150902
3   Lisa    Anderson     projB  20150801
3   Lisa    Anderson     projC  20150903
4   Nancy   Johnson      projB  20150601
4   Nancy   Johnson      projC  20150822
4   Nancy   Johnson      projE  20150904
5   Chris   Edwards      projA  20150905
```

I need to split it into rows for the id, fname, lname, and parsing the projects and proddates into separate records.  I have found many posts with split functions and I can get it to work for 1 column, but not 2.  When I do 2 columns it permeates the split.  ie for John Doe, it gives me records for projA 3 times, once for each of the proddates.  I need to coorelate each multivalue project record with only it's respective projdate and not the others.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: please post your expected resultset

Comment: Although this is not a good approach for storing data (denormalized) but since this has sent to you by someone else, you might not have option. If you do have option to normalize it, please do so or convince the opposite party. For the current concern, can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: what happens when the projects and proj dates counts don't match? e.g. there are 4 projects but 5 project numbers.  Even if they are always equal are you assuming that the first element in one list always corresponds to the first element in the second list?

Comment: I can't for the life of me understand why people give down votes to a question.  I have a question!  Why be a rude jerk?  I have looked everywhere and can only find solutions for splitting one column, but not 2 or more related columns.  What I am trying to do is to normalize the data.  There are like 30 columns in this data, and groups of them relate to each other with the first few being singular record data.  I will post the table of what I want the result to look like in an edit.  I can say that the columns that relate to each other always match.  Their delimiters, anyway.

Comment: Well, a *better* question would include expected results, and discuss edge cases - e.g. we can see there seems to be a skipped value for ID 2 - `;;` should that produce a result? Also, the other comments here are suggesting other edge cases to consider (what do we do if projects is `ABC;DEF` and projdates is `20150101;20150201;20150301`)

Comment: Also, I've realised that I've assumed [tag:sql-server] but that may not be warranted. In the edit, please also add a tag for your database system.

Comment: the skipped one was a bad example.  There might be a value in one column and not another, but the point I wanted to make is that the delimiters will still be equal, so nulls need to be preserved.  I get that the question may not be awesome, but I am stuck on something so the question may have some of my confusion in it.  It just seems rude and bullyish to down-vote a question.

Comment: If NULLs are to be preserved, I can see where Projects might not have ProjDates, (e.g. the project might not be completed, etc.) but could an input row be encountered where a ProjDate would be provided without a corresponding Project?  Seems to me that if projects and dates aren't 1:1, then you wouldn't know where to apply the NULL in the shorter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Jeff Moden's "[DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)" splitter (Which I have renamed here "fDelimitedSplit8K") 
(Ref. Figure 21: *The Final "New" Splitter Code, Ready for Testing*) 
to do the heavy lifting for the splits, the rest becomes fairly straightforward, using CROSS APPLY and WHERE to get the proper joining.

```
IF object_ID (N'tempdb..#tInputData') is not null 
   DROP TABLE #tInputData

CREATE TABLE #tInputData (
     ID        INT 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  -- Add IDENTITY if ID needs to be set at INSERT time
   , FName     VARCHAR (30)
   , LName     VARCHAR (30)
   , Projects  VARCHAR (4000)
   , ProjDates VARCHAR (4000)
)

INSERT INTO #tInputData
         ( ID, FName, LName, Projects, ProjDates )
VALUES
   ( 1, 'John',  'Doe'      , 'projA;projB;projC' , '20150701;20150801;20150901'),
   ( 2, 'Jane',  'Smith'    , 'projD;;projC'      , '20150701;;20150902'),
   ( 3, 'Lisa',  'Anderson' , 'projB;projC'       , '20150801;20150903'),
   ( 4, 'Nancy', 'Johnson'  , 'projB;projC;projE' , '20150601;20150822;20150904'),
   ( 5, 'Chris', 'Edwards'  , 'projA'             , '20150905')

SELECT * FROM #tInputData  -- Take a look at the INSERT results

; WITH ResultSet  AS 
(
   SELECT 
        InData.ID
      , InData.FName
      , InData.LName
      , ProjectList.ItemNumber AS ProjectID
      , ProjectList.Item AS Project
      , DateList.ItemNumber AS DateID
      , DateList.Item AS ProjDate
   FROM #tInputData AS InData
   CROSS APPLY dbo.fDelimitedSplit8K(InData.Projects,';') AS ProjectList
   CROSS APPLY dbo.fDelimitedSplit8K(InData.ProjDates,';') AS DateList
   WHERE DateList.ItemNumber = ProjectList.ItemNumber  -- Links projects and dates in left-to-r1ght order
   AND (ProjectList.Item <> '' AND DateList.Item <> '') -- Ignore input lines when both Projects and ProjDates have no value; note that these aren't NULLs.
)
SELECT 
      ID
    , FName
    , LName
    , Project
    , ProjDate 
FROM ResultSet
ORDER BY ID, Project
```

Results in

```
ID  FName  LName     Project  ProjDate  
--  -----  --------  -------  --------  
 1  John   Doe       projA    20150701  
 1  John   Doe       projB    20150801  
 1  John   Doe       projC    20150901  
 2  Jane   Smith     projC    20150902  
 2  Jane   Smith     projD    20150701  
 3  Lisa   Anderson  projB    20150801  
 3  Lisa   Anderson  projC    20150903  
 4  Nancy  Johnson   projB    20150601  
 4  Nancy  Johnson   projC    20150822  
 4  Nancy  Johnson   projE    20150904  
 5  Chris  Edwards   projA    20150905
```

This algorithm handles Project and Date lists of equal length.  Should one list be shorter than the other for a given row, some special attention will be needed to apply the NULL in the proper place.

```
-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #tInputData
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this out!  I am going to try it now!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you're expected results are, but this may be a good starting point:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null,fname varchar(17) not null,lname varchar(15) not null,
projects varchar(76) not null,projdates varchar(310) not null)
insert into @t(ID,fname,lname,projects,projdates) values
(1,'John', 'Doe',     'projA;projB;projC','20150701;20150801;20150901'),
(2,'Jane', 'Smith',   'projD;;projC',     '20150701;;20150902'        ),
(3,'Lisa', 'Anderson','projB;projC',      '20150801;20150903'         ),
(4,'Nancy','Johnson', 'projB;projC;projE','20150601;20150822;20150904'),
(5,'Chris','Edwards', 'projA',            '20150905'                  )

;With Numbers as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number) n
    from master..spt_values
), ProjectPositions as (
    select ID,n.n
    from @t t
        inner join
        Numbers n
            on SUBSTRING(t.projects,n.n,1) = ';'
    union all
    select ID,0 from @t
    union all
    select ID,LEN(projects)+1 from @t
), ProjectsNumbered as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY n) rn
    from ProjectPositions
), ProjectPartitions as (
    select n1.ID,n1.n+1 as startat,n2.n as endat,n1.rn
    from ProjectsNumbered n1
            inner join
        ProjectsNumbered n2
            on
                n1.id = n2.id and
                n1.rn = n2.rn -1
), ProDatePositions as (
    select ID,n.n
    from @t t
        inner join
        Numbers n
            on SUBSTRING(t.projdates,n.n,1) = ';'
    union all
    select ID,0 from @t
    union all
    select ID,LEN(projdates)+1 from @t
), ProDateNumbered as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY n) rn
    from ProDatePositions
), ProDatePartitions as (
    select n1.ID,n1.n+1 as startat,n2.n as endat,n1.rn
    from ProDateNumbered n1
            inner join
        ProDateNumbered n2
            on
                n1.id = n2.id and
                n1.rn = n2.rn -1
)
select
    t.ID,t.fname,t.lname,
    SUBSTRING(projects,pp.startat,pp.endat - pp.startat) as project,
    SUBSTRING(projdates,pdp.startat,pdp.endat - pdp.startat) as projdate
from
    @t t
        inner join
    ProjectPartitions pp
        on
            t.ID = pp.ID
        inner join
    ProDatePartitions pdp
        on
            t.ID = pdp.ID and
            pp.rn = pdp.rn
```

Results:

```
ID          fname             lname           project     projdate
----------- ----------------- --------------- ----------- ----------
1           John              Doe             projA       20150701
1           John              Doe             projB       20150801
1           John              Doe             projC       20150901
2           Jane              Smith           projD       20150701
2           Jane              Smith                       
2           Jane              Smith           projC       20150902
3           Lisa              Anderson        projB       20150801
3           Lisa              Anderson        projC       20150903
4           Nancy             Johnson         projB       20150601
4           Nancy             Johnson         projC       20150822
4           Nancy             Johnson         projE       20150904
5           Chris             Edwards         projA       20150905
```

(It's unclear what you wanted to do for the "empty" project for `ID` 2)

---

How it works - we dummy up a `Numbers` table using `ROW_NUMBER()` - we're querying an undocumented table in `master` but we're not using any actual values from the table - it's just known to have a good number of rows. If you have a real numbers table, you can skip that CTE.

We then do the same operations twice - we join the numbers table to our data table and use it to find the positions of `;` characters within the string we want to split. We also create a pair of dummy results for position 0 (before the start of the string) and for 1 position past the end of the string. This defines `ProjectPositions` and `ProDatePositions`

We numbers these positions using another `ROW_NUMBER()` (`ProjectNumbered`, `ProDateNumbered` and then use that information to join successive rows together (`ProjectPartitions`, `ProDatePartitions`). Then end result is that we have computed where we should extract substrings from both strings.

Finally, we join these "paritition" CTEs back to the original data table, and we use row numbers to ensure that we align the partitioning information from the two independent strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this following query.

SELECT A.ID  ,a.fname,a.lname ,a.projects  ,
     ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS projdates
 FROM  (SELECT ID , fname,   lname ,     projects, 
         CAST ('' + REPLACE([projdates], ';', '') + '' AS XML) AS String
     FROM  ) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);

Try with this you will get the your expected output.

Thanks.

Comment: but won't this only split out the project dates and not the projects with them?  I tried some cross apply/split functions and they don't seem to work for splitting 2 or more columns in 1 go.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer (DB: SQL Server 2019)

```
select  name, Location_Type, b.value as spltrows from Location__c  A
CROSS APPLY string_split(A.Location_Type,';') b
where Location_Type is not null
ORDER BY 1
```

In Location_Type column we have multi-values like "Mailing;Shipping;Billing"